# Qt5 QML - Texts don't load in deployed version of application

Tags: qml, qt5

Using qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw482_opengl-5.3.2.exe and Qt Creator with it, I wrote a Qt5 QML Qt Quick application and every thing is OK during compile time and running on my own system. But when I move this release exe to an another computer, none of texts loads and display outs.

How can I solve this strange behavior?

main.cpp:

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
    #include <QDir>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        app.addLibraryPath(QString(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QApplication::applicationDirPath())));

        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
        engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

        return app.exec();
    }
```

main.qml:

```
    import QtQuick 2.3
    import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

    ApplicationWindow {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("Hello World")

        menuBar: MenuBar {
            Menu {
                title: qsTr("File")
                MenuItem {
                    text: qsTr("&Open")
                    onTriggered: console.log("Open action triggered");
                }
                MenuItem {
                    text: qsTr("Exit")
                    onTriggered: Qt.quit();
                }
            }
        }

        Text {
            text: qsTr("Hello World")
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
```

the texts of the menuBar and the Text in the QML above disappered on some other computer!

the DebugView log below shows that it seems the question rests with OpenGL?

```
00000001    0.00000000  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenFramebuffers'    
00000002    0.00005326  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenFramebuffersOES' 
00000003    0.00010398  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenFramebuffersARB' 
00000004    0.00015181  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenFramebuffersEXT' 
00000005    0.00051232  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffers' 
00000006    0.00056050  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersOES'  
00000007    0.00060760  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersARB'  
00000008    0.00065434  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersEXT'  
00000009    0.00222535  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebuffer'    
00000010    0.00227571  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebufferOES' 
00000011    0.00232462  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebufferARB' 
00000012    0.00237209  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebufferEXT' 
00000013    0.00248694  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffers' 
00000014    0.00253477  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersOES'  
00000015    0.00258150  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersARB'  
00000016    0.00262861  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersEXT'  
00000017    0.00267643  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000018    0.00272317  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000019    0.00276991  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000020    0.00281665  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000021    0.00286411  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferData' 
00000022    0.00295505  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataOES'  
00000023    0.00300288  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataARB'  
00000024    0.00304998  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataEXT'  
00000025    0.00310034  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffers' 
00000026    0.00314708  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersOES'  
00000027    0.00319346  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersARB'  
00000028    0.00324092  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersEXT'  
00000029    0.00328911  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000030    0.00333512  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000031    0.00338150  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000032    0.00342787  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000033    0.00347498  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferData' 
00000034    0.00352135  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataOES'  
00000035    0.00356773  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataARB'  
00000036    0.00361374  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataEXT'  
00000037    0.00366193  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffers' 
00000038    0.00370831  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersOES'  
00000039    0.00375468  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersARB'  
00000040    0.00380070  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersEXT'  
00000041    0.00384816  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000042    0.00389454  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000043    0.00394055  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000044    0.00398693  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000045    0.00403439  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferData' 
00000046    0.00408113  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataOES'  
00000047    0.00413729  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataARB'  
00000048    0.00418475  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataEXT'  
00000049    0.00592387  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000050    0.00597605  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000051    0.00602278  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000052    0.00606916  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000053    0.00612061  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000054    0.00616699  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000055    0.00621336  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000056    0.00625938  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000057    0.00635503  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgram'  
00000058    0.00640249  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramARB'   
00000059    0.00644996  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObject'    
00000060    0.00649778  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObjectARB' 
00000061    0.00657387  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program    
00000062    0.00674198  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000063    0.00678981  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000064    0.00683727  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000065    0.00688437  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000066    0.00693075  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000067    0.00701082  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000068    0.00705828  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000069    0.00710647  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000070    0.00715357  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000071    0.00719923  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000072    0.00725828  [4068] shader compilation failed:   
00000073    0.00725828  [4068] ""   
00000074    0.00730973  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked    
00000075    0.00735756  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is not linked 
00000076    0.00740575  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( textureScale ): shader program is not linked  
00000077    0.00745683  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000078    0.00750393  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000079    0.00755031  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000080    0.00759705  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000081    0.00764415  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000082    0.00769053  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000083    0.00773727  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000084    0.00778328  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000085    0.00783654  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgram'  
00000086    0.00788328  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramARB'   
00000087    0.00793002  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObject'    
00000088    0.00797676  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObjectARB' 
00000089    0.00802277  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program    
00000090    0.00810683  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000091    0.00815465  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000092    0.00820139  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000093    0.00824849  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000094    0.00829451  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000095    0.00836407  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000096    0.00841154  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000097    0.00845791  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000098    0.00850465  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000099    0.00855030  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000100    0.00859994  [4068] shader compilation failed:   
00000101    0.00859994  [4068] ""   
00000102    0.00864922  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( qt_Matrix ): shader program is not linked 
00000103    0.00869704  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked   
00000104    0.00874595  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000105    0.00879269  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000106    0.00883835  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000107    0.00888472  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000108    0.00893182  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000109    0.00897820  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000110    0.00902421  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000111    0.00907023  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000112    0.00913508  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgram'  
00000113    0.00918363  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramARB'   
00000114    0.00923073  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObject'    
00000115    0.00927711  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObjectARB' 
00000116    0.00932312  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program    
00000117    0.00939812  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000118    0.00944486  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000119    0.00949160  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000120    0.00953870  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000121    0.00958435  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000122    0.00965283  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000123    0.00969957  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000124    0.00974558  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000125    0.00979269  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000126    0.00983798  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000127    0.00988725  [4068] shader compilation failed:   
00000128    0.00988725  [4068] ""   
00000129    0.00993580  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( qt_Matrix ): shader program is not linked 
00000130    0.00998363  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked   
00000131    0.01003689  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000132    0.01008326  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000133    0.01013073  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000134    0.01017710  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000135    0.01022421  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000136    0.01027022  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000137    0.01031623  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000138    0.01036261  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000139    0.01229194  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebuffer'    
00000140    0.01233687  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebufferOES' 
00000141    0.01238506  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebufferARB' 
00000142    0.01243216  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebufferEXT' 
00000143    0.01325426  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000144    0.01330100  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000145    0.01334773  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000146    0.01339447  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000147    0.01344447  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000148    0.01349121  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000149    0.01353759  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000150    0.01358433  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000151    0.01364556  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgram'  
00000152    0.01369266  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramARB'   
00000153    0.01374012  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObject'    
00000154    0.01378795  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObjectARB' 
00000155    0.01383650  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program    
00000156    0.01394012  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000157    0.01398831  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000158    0.01403505  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000159    0.01408215  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000160    0.01412889  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000161    0.01420026  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000162    0.01424664  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000163    0.01429410  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000164    0.01434048  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000165    0.01438650  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000166    0.01443649  [4068] shader compilation failed:   
00000167    0.01443649  [4068] ""   
00000168    0.01448686  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked    
00000169    0.01453505  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is not linked 
00000170    0.01458323  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( textureScale ): shader program is not linked  
00000171    0.01463396  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000172    0.01468033  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000173    0.01472707  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000174    0.01477272  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000175    0.01482019  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000176    0.01486620  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000177    0.01491258  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000178    0.01495823  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000179    0.01501185  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgram'  
00000180    0.01505823  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramARB'   
00000181    0.01511584  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObject'    
00000182    0.01516439  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObjectARB' 
00000183    0.01521076  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program    
00000184    0.01528613  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000185    0.01533359  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000186    0.01538033  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000187    0.01542743  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000188    0.01547308  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000189    0.01554192  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000190    0.01558902  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000191    0.01563612  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000192    0.01568250  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000193    0.01572815  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000194    0.01577743  [4068] shader compilation failed:   
00000195    0.01577743  [4068] ""   
00000196    0.01582634  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( qt_Matrix ): shader program is not linked 
00000197    0.01587417  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked   
00000198    0.01592308  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000199    0.01596946  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000200    0.01601583  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000201    0.01606185  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000202    0.01611003  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000203    0.01615641  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000204    0.01620243  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000205    0.01624808  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000206    0.01630025  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgram'  
00000207    0.01634699  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramARB'   
00000208    0.01639300  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObject'    
00000209    0.01643974  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObjectARB' 
00000210    0.01648503  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program    
00000211    0.01656329  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000212    0.01660568  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000213    0.01665242  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000214    0.01669952  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000215    0.01674481  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000216    0.01681329  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'   
00000217    0.01686039  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'    
00000218    0.01690713  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject' 
00000219    0.01695351  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'  
00000220    0.01699880  [4068] QOpenGLShader: could not create shader   
00000221    0.01704807  [4068] shader compilation failed:   
00000222    0.01704807  [4068] ""   
00000223    0.01709807  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( qt_Matrix ): shader program is not linked 
00000224    0.01714553  [4068] QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked   
00000225    0.01719988  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000226    0.01724590  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000227    0.01729227  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000228    0.01733829  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'  
00000229    0.01738539  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer' 
00000230    0.01743140  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'  
00000231    0.01747742  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'  
00000232    0.01752343  [4068] getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'
```

Comment: You will need to add more information to your question, including relevant code. See [how to ask a good SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Comment: Run [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) on the other computer and let us know if there are any errors.

Comment: @Mitch @i alarmed alien

Comment: more information added. thx! @ialarmedalien

Comment: more information added. thx! @Mitch

Comment: @koopajah thank you for your previous answer elsewhere, follow that I solved my problem now, but a new question is: instead of direct log on, using windows remote desktop log on to the an another computer, problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Something's definitely fishy with the OpenGL on that computer, as you mentioned. As a workaround, you can use the ANGLE version of Qt that doesn't rely on OpenGL and uses DirectX instead.

You can get such a version by going to http://qt-project.org/downloads and clicking "Show Downloads". For example, you could try "Qt 5.3.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, 561 MB)".

Comment: thank you for your answer, I solved my problem now, but a new question is: instead of direct log on, using windows remote desktop log on to the an another computer, problem still exists.

Comment: and where to find ANGLE version of Qt 5.3.2 with Qt Creator?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include that info. How did you solve your problem? You might want to answer your own question with the solution.

Comment: thx！OpenGL 2.0 is need, so I updated graphic card driver and then those texts displayed out.

Comment: @hao Please answer your question by clicking the "Answer Your Question" button. That way other people will know what to do when they experience the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL 2.0 is need, so I updated graphic card driver and then those texts displayed out.